# How to find out if a web template is missing from a site collection

Tags: 2007, error, migration, site-template, import

Is there any utility out there that can tell me if there is any custom web template missing or faulty from a site collection,

I keep getting error   "WEB template #00000 not found" while importing a Exported site collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any way you could find out that a web template is faulty or missing for a site collection.

However the error I was getting was because site collection was customized and someone deleted web template which was referenced in the site definition of site collection.

I solved problem by creating a new site collection using site definition again and also by adding web templates to 12 hive.

Hope it helps anyone get same kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

You could use powershell to access the SharePoint object model.

The site's template ID is a property of SPWeb.  (SPweb.WebTemplateID)

Then you would compare this integer to the list of site template ID numbers : http://mosshowto.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/sharepoint-list-template-ids.html

plus on msdn has this article, if you know the template then you can fix or restore it using stsadm.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909677.aspx

hope this helps

Comment: my question is, How would I know if a web template is missing or faulty :S

Comment: the thing is you dont know until you migrate it to another site or unpgrate it form 2007 to 2010 where youll get the errors popping up and thats where you would use the methods above ;)